# String formating unexpected result

Tags: c#, format

Why are these 2 lines show different values? Is it because {0:18}"? Why? Thanks.

```
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("da-DK")));           //-12,46 kr.
Console.WriteLine("{0,-18}",value.ToString("C"), CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("da-DK")); //($12.46)
```

Comment: in case of `Console.WriteLine("{0,-18}",value.ToString("C"), CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("da-DK"));` the second parameter (`Culture`) treats as an ordinal parameter (like `value`)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko,  oh yes, very good point, could you please make this an answer so that I could accept it? Thanks.

Comment: `value.ToString("C")` has no explicit formatter, so it uses the current system culture, which would be US in your case... Thats why the $12.46...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it because `{0:18}`?

No. In the first case, you're formatting your value as string a using the "C" format specifier, and using the Danish culture.

In the second case, you're formatting your value as string a using the "C" format specifier using the *default* culture... and then including that string value in *another* format operation. You're passing the Danish culture as a second, unused format argument, but even if you passed it in the right place, it would be irrelevant by that point, as when you format a *string*, it always just stays as it is, regardless of culture.

I suspect you *actually* want this:

```cs
string text = value.ToString("C", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("da-DK"));
Console.WriteLine("{0,-18}", text);
```

Or to do all the string formatting in one operation:

```cs
string text = string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("da-DK"), "{0,-18:C}", value);
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

(As far as I can tell, `Console.WriteLine` has no overload permitting the culture to be specified.)

Answer (score 1):

The culture parameter treats differently in these calls; for the 1st fragment

```
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("da-DK")));
```

we have `value` converted to `string` treating `value` as being *currency* (`"C"`) of Danemark (`CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("da-DK")`). On the contrary for

```
Console.WriteLine("{0,-18}",value.ToString("C"), CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("da-DK"));
```

we have efficiently `String.Format` (`"{0,-18}"`) call with two parameters:

1. `value.ToString("C")` - `value` as *default* culture (not necessary `da-DK`) *currency*, so it can be, say, `"15.47$"`
2. `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("da-DK")` which is ignored (no `{1}` in the format)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I found that the answer was extended beyond my question but provided a solution I could use (even though I did not explicityl ask for!). Thanks again.